# How does html handle overlapping tags?

Tags: html

For example:

```
<b>Hello <i>there </b>friend</i>
```

Can html handle overlapping tags, like shown in the example?

Comment: why don't you try yourself and see

Comment: tl;dr not a terrible question. One should always try things and see for oneself. That doesn't necessarily mean the result is universal/contractual/dependable. Digging through specs isn't easy for the uninitiated. Questions like this can help get advice and *insight* from more expert users, information that's not necessarily otherwise all available in a single place. Questions like this are usually the result of one's best effort to articulate a deeper curiosity on an unfamiliar topic, and being willing to ask such questions helps prevent issues like "works fine on my machine" down the road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML handles the problem by simply forbidding the syntax. It is invalid.

Browsers have error recovery strategies, but you shouldn't aim to trigger them.

HTML 5 has a **non-normative** [error recovery strategy for this case](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#misnested-tags:-b-i-/b-/i).

Browsers that follow it would parse:

> ```
> <b>Hello <i>there </b>friend</i>
> ```

as if it were

```
<b>Hello <i>there </i></b><i>friend</i>
```

Answer (score -2):

Combining `i` and `b` is totally fine, however, you need to make sure to nest them correctly.

```
<b>Hello <i>there </i></b><i>friend</i>
```