# Wrapping user highlighted text inside a span; dealing with overlapping tags?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I'm trying to make it possible to highlight text on a page, and "remember" the selection by wrapping it in a colored span. Example:
Before highlighting:

```
<span>this is just <b>sample</b> text</span>
```

After highlighting "just":

```
<span>this is <span class="user-selected">just</span> <b>sample</b> text</span>
```

However, the current implementation allows for overlapping tags, for instance, if "just s" were highlighted the result would be

```
<span>this is <span class="user-selected">just <b>s</span>ample</b> text</span>
```

which is undesirable, but it seems unavoidable. I realize the browser can [ignore this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797234/how-does-html-handle-overlapping-tags), and I could modify the selection to be split in two

```
<span>this is <span class="user-selected">just </span><b><span class="user-selected">s</span>ample</b> text</span>
```

However, the example above is simplified, and the page will involve MathML expressions, so the highlighted span could involve 3 opening tags and 17 closing tags. Splitting the span into 15 parts seems excessive, when it should be a single part, so I was wondering if that is the only option, or if there are alternatives?