# How to make multiple overlapping annotations/markings, with different styles, in markdown

Tags: markdown

I would like to know if there is a way to annotate/mark text in markdown as shown in this figure,

[image]

There are two different colored highlights and an underlining style in a third color. The three annotation/markings overlap as well.

Is this possible in markdown? If not, is it possible in any other simple markup language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown doesn't support anything like this. It's a very simple language.

HTML is a first-class citizen in Markdown, and it gets you closer. But since HTML [doesn't permit misnested tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44797234/354577), to reliably get the result you want you'll have to explicitly start and stop each combination of styles.

For example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".md").forEach(function(e) {
  e.innerHTML = marked.parse(e.innerHTML);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: x-large;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: #fef3c0;
}

.bg-orange {
  background-color: #ffe3c5;
}

.u-purple {
  text-decoration: underline #9f56ff;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>

<div class="md">
  <span class="bg-yellow">If water comes directly from a good,
    </span><span class="bg-yellow u-purple">pretreated source, then no additional purification is needed;
    </span><span class="u-purple"> otherwise, pretreat water before use.
    </span><span class="u-purple bg-orange">Store water in
    sturdy,</span><span class="bg-orange"> leak-proof, breakage-resistant containers.</span>
  Consider using plastic bottles commonly...
</div>
```

Note that I made sure to jam each `<span>` right up against the preceding `</span>` where appropriate to avoid unstyled whitespace.

Not very convenient, but certainly possible if you're generating the HTML.